# Regex - math with cycle

Tags: regex

How to count the amount of a match inside itself to skip some characters?

Example:

I have:

`(a(b(c)))`

If I run this regex: `\(.+?\)`

It will be return: `(a(b(c)`

But what I want is the `)` that closes the loop, that is, the third.

I could just remove the `?` From the regex but there is a problem:

Ex: `\(.+\)` to `(a)(a(b(c)))` return `(a)(a(b(c)))`

And what I want is for the `group` to return to me with the closed loop of (), that is, it should return 2 matchs to me:

match 1: `(a)`
match 2: `(a(b(c)))`

What is the question of counting in the match? Well, what I thought was if there is any way to count how many `(` passed to know how many `)` one should skip, that is:

```
1   2   3   1 2 3
( a ( b ( c ) ) )
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this just using regex?

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich Worse than kkkk, but the problem is that in this situation, I really need to use a regular expression

Comment: Why do you NEED to use a regex? What's wrong with a counter that tracks open and close parens?

Comment: Regex is one of my top tags, this is a problem where a different solution should be tried if possible. To me, the solution you chose is unreadable.

Comment: @JeffC college work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *need* to use regex, please try the recursive regex `(?R)`.
The implementation depends on the language so let me explain it with `python`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import regex

str ='(a)(a(b(c)))'

m = regex.findall(r'\((?:[^()]|(?R))+\)', str)
print(m)
```

Output:

```
['(a)', '(a(b(c)))']
```

Explanation of the regex pattern `\((?:[^()]|(?R))+\)`:

- The inner part `(?:[^()]|(?R))+` matches:

  - one or more `[^()]` or `(?R)` where

    - `[^()]` matches any character other than parentheses.
    - `(?R)` represents the entire regex `\((?:[^()]|(?R))+\)` recursively.

Comment: You are the best hahah, tk